# the request has been sent in flutter to django server and it has returned a response but the condition is still false

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to send an otp to user from flutter to the django sever and it is sending in the next page I have to check the otp and return the result from api to app in this part I wrote a variable "statusCode" which is null and in the post method I said the statuscode = response.statusCode and in the verify button I said if statusCode == 200 then go to home screen and else return a snack bar this is my otp screen code. in the output it returns statuscode 200 but in the application it returns snackbar what I'll have to do?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:pinput/pinput.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/Model/ChatModel.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/Screens/home/HomeScreen.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/common/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/utils/theme_manager.dart';

class OTPScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const OTPScreen(
      {Key? key,
      required this.chatModels,
      required this.sourceChat,
      required this.phoneNumber})
      : super(key: key);
  final List<ChatModel> chatModels;
  final ChatModel sourceChat;
  final String phoneNumber;

  @override
  State<OTPScreen> createState() => _OTPScreenState();
}

class _OTPScreenState extends State<OTPScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map otp = {};
    int? statusCode;
    bool isLoading = false;
    bool timeOut = false;
    void sendOTP(String otp) async {
      try {
        Response response = await post(
            Uri.parse("https://2858-151-240-216-221.ngrok-free.app/otp-api/"),
            body: {"otp": otp, "phone_number": widget.phoneNumber});
        print(response.body);
        setState(() {
          statusCode = response.statusCode;
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
      }
    }

    TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
    final defaultPinTheme = PinTheme(
      width: 56,
      height: 56,
      textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(30, 60, 87, 1),
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Color.fromRGBO(234, 239, 243, 1)),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
    );

    final focusedPinTheme = defaultPinTheme.copyDecorationWith(
      border: Border.all(color: Color.fromRGBO(114, 178, 238, 1)),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    );

    final submittedPinTheme = defaultPinTheme.copyWith(
      decoration: defaultPinTheme.decoration?.copyWith(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(234, 239, 243, 1),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor:
          ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context) ? primaryColor : Colors.white,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded,
            color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                ? Colors.white
                : Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                'assets/otp.png',
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 25,
              ),
              Text(
                "Phone Verification",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                        ? Colors.white
                        : Colors.black),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Text(
                "We need to register your phone without getting started!",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                        ? Colors.white
                        : Colors.black),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Pinput(
                length: 6,
                controller: controller,
                showCursor: true,
                onCompleted: (pin) => print(pin),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 45,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: tabColor,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
                  onPressed: () {
                    sendOTP(controller.text);
                    if (statusCode != null) {
                      if (statusCode == 200) {
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (builder) => HomeScreen(
                              chatModels: widget.chatModels,
                              sourceChat: widget.sourceChat,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        showSnackBar(context: context, content: "try again");
                      }
                    }
                    else {
                      showSnackBar(context: context, content: "check your connection");
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    "Verify Phone Number",
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Edit Phone Number ?",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.black),
                      ))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to employ `async` and `await` in your code to ensure it waits for a response from the server. Update your code to make it behave as follows when the user presses:

```
 onPressed: () async {
                 await sendOTP(controller.text);
                    if (statusCode != null) {
                      if (statusCode == 200) {
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (builder) => HomeScreen(
                              chatModels: widget.chatModels,
                              sourceChat: widget.sourceChat,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        showSnackBar(context: context, content: "try again");
                      }
                    }
                    else {
                      showSnackBar(context: context, content: "check your connection");
                    }
                  },
```